# Run multiple animations with SCNAnimation

Tags: ios, core-animation, scenekit, ios11

Hi I am new to SceneKit  I want to run multiple animations, one after another, in SceneKit. I've implemented only one animation but I don't know how to fix the duration of one animation.
The Apple documentation is not finished yet.
I followed Fox2 Apple Sample Code and I used SCNAnimation that is no well documented

Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used run Timer to limit animation duration and I followed the API

```
character.addAnimationPlayer(sayHi, forKey: "anim")
character.animationPlayer(forKey: animationName)?.paused = true
```